# JQuery ajax call does not hit the controller when clicked the second time

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to achieve load more data functionality in mvc project using ajax. So I have followed this approach : 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1043142/Implementing-Load-More-Button-using-ASP-NET-MVC-an

Everything seems fine but when I click on the load more data button for the first time it hits the controller but brings up the same data that was initially loaded already. Then when I try to click on the button again it does not even hit the controller for me to debug instead, it brings up the same initial data once again. There's no error in the console by the way. Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new HomePageViewModel
      {               
        InitiallyLoadedPosts = _postService.GetAllPosts(new GetPostsInput { IsPublished = true, ReturnCount = 4 })              
      };
    return View(model);
}


    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult LoadMorePost(int size)
    {
        var model = new LoadMorePostsViewModel { Posts = _postService.GetAllPosts(new GetPostsInput { IsPublished = true, SkipCount = size, ReturnCount = 4 }) };
        int modelCount = model.Posts.Count();
        if (model.Posts.Any())
        {
            string modelString = RenderRazorViewToString("_LoadMorePost", model);

            return Json(new { ModelString = modelString, ModelCount = modelCount });
        }
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                                     viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                         ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Here is my Index html

```
@foreach (var post in Model.LoadMorePosts.Batch(4))
    {
        foreach (var subPost in post)
        {            
            <article class="cb-blog-style-b cb-module-a cb-article cb-article-row-2 cb-article-row cb-img-above-meta clearfix cb-separated @(cssClass) post type-post status-publish format-video has-post-thumbnail hentry category-design">
                // data binding
            </article>
        }
    }
    <a id="loadMore" href="#">Load More</a>


   // string rendered view : 
   @foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
   {
     <article class="cb-blog-style-b cb-module-a cb-article cb-article-row-2 cb-article-row cb-img-above-meta clearfix cb-separated cb-no-2 post-111 post type-post status-publish format-video has-post-thumbnail hentry category-design tag-food tag-health tag-lorem tag-vintage post_format-post-format-video">
    // string rendered view.
    </article>
    }
```

Here is my Ajax call

```
(function () {
$(function () {
    var loadCount = 1;
    $("#loadMore").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: Url.Action("LoadMorePost", "Home"),
            data: { size: loadCount * 4 }.serialize(),
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length !== 0) {
                    $(data.ModelString).insertBefore("#loadMore").hide().fadeIn(2000);
                }
                var ajaxModelCount = data.ModelCount - (loadCount * 4);
                if (ajaxModelCount <= 0) {
                    $("#loadMore").hide().fadeOut(2000);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                alert("message : \n" + "An error occurred, for more info check the js console" + "\n status : \n" + status + " \n error : \n" + error);
            }
        });
        loadCount = loadCount + 1;
    });
});
})();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your element with `id="loadMore"`? If that is being replaced in the first ajax call, then you need to use event delegation = `$(document).on('click', '#loadMore', function() { ....` (and why not just return a partial view rather than json?)

Comment: `$("#loadMore").hide()`. Once you get a result you're hiding the element that causes the click event...

Comment: @ADyson - only when there are no results.

Comment: Where is "loadCount" defined? Is it actually incrementing each time?

Comment: @RikLewis probably, but we don't know the value of loadCount, or the value of data.ModelCount. That equation could easily be causing an unintentional fadeout depending on its value.

Comment: @ADyson - agreed.

Comment: i have added my element with id="loadMore" to index.html forgot to put it sorry and loadCount is defined at the top of the js file.

Comment: @user3055125 what is the expected value of data.ModelCount? Will it be equal to the number of results returned? And, why do you increment loadCount outside the ajax "success" call? Surely it should only increment if the call completes ok? Ajax is asynchronous, so it's likely that loadCount will be incremented before the ajax call returns. That might put your results out. What are the circumstances in which you want to run the `$("#loadMore").hide().fadeOut(2000);` command? (Bearing in mind this will prevent any more ajax calls from being made).

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: @ADyson value of data.ModelCount should return the total data count that is stored in database. There's no console error, everytime i click on the button it returns the same data and hits no action in the controller

Comment: @user3055125 GetAllPosts should return 4 results each time, right? And ModelCount is set to `model.Posts.Count()`. So I think this will always be 4? Is that what you expect? How many rows do you actually have in total? is GetAllPosts definitely working correctly? That's the only code you haven't shown, the rest of it I think will be ok, except: 1) really you should move `loadCount = loadCount + 1;` into the "success" function to be certain that the value will be correct at all times. 2) I think LoadMore will be hidden sooner than you think if ModelCount is always 4.

Comment: @ADyson GetAllPosts should return 4 results each time, that's right. I will set it to 16 when I accomplish this functionality. I have at least 100 rows in the database. GetAllPosts is my service and working correclty, I may share it's code aswell if you want me to. I will try your suggestions and will let you know whether or not it's working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok. So if ModelCount is always 4. Let's say that loadCount = 2. In that case `var ajaxModelCount = data.ModelCount - (loadCount * 4);` will equate to `4-8`, which equals `-4`. This will cause the LoadMore button to be hidden, and you can't load any more posts (even though you have 100 possible ones). Surely you want to allow all posts to be loaded?

Comment: @ADyson I have followed through your suggestions but still no luck. First time it hits the controller action I debug it and my service returns the expected data as it should, but in the .insertBefore("#loadMore") area wrong data emerges all the time. And the most interesting part of it wrong data appears in the page even before ajax call hits the action just like the data is stored in cache and shows up immediately i click which is really confusing.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "wrong data"? Be specific. Not the records you're expecting? Or in the wrong format or something? And the second thing just seems impossible. Are you completely sure? The data can't be shown before it's returned by the server. If caching was happening it wouldn't bother calling the action method at all. All the same, clear your browser cache and try again just to be 100% certain.

Comment: @ADyson I've meant unexpected data by saying wrong data, sorry for my english.Second thing might seem impossible but even if my service returns the expected data when i debug, insertBefore("#loadMore") area is being loaded with the data that is initially loaded already. it keeps returning 4 of the initially loaded data everytime i click on the load more button. to make it more clear i should say after clicking 4 of load more button i have 20x repetitive same data like (row1,row2,row3,row4 they are loaded initially, after i click the button row1,row2,row3,row4,row1,row2,row3,row4 ) it goes on.

Comment: ok. that would imply that `_postService.GetAllPosts` is always returning the same data, regardless of the `size` parameter. Can you set breakpoints and inspect the C# variables to be sure that a) `size` has the value you expect, and b) `_postService.GetAllPosts` is returning the data you expect?

Comment: @ADyson actually no, _postService.GetAllPosts returns expected data like row5,row6,row7,row8 but  the data does not show up in the place where it should be insertBefore("#loadMore"). Instead, after second click without hitting the action ajax returns row1,row2,row3,row4 repetitively. It's so strange.

Comment: can I just check something. On the times that it _does_ hit the controller, which of the "return" statements is getting used? 1. `return Json(new { ModelString = modelString, ModelCount = modelCount });` or 2. ` return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` I've just noticed that this makes no sense - you never want to use number 2, because it will return JSON when your script is expecting HTML. Even if your Posts variable contains no items, you should still send it to the partial view, it will just return an empty string.

Comment: And also, can you show us the razor code for the `LoadMorePost` partial view?

Comment: And finally sorry, when you do the second click and it appears not to hit the controller, are there any error messages in the console? Can you confirm (via the network tab) that no ajax call is being made? Maybe doing some `console.log()`s in your script as well would be helpful to see exactly which parts of the code are running.